# GridView- binding to groups of different ViewModels? (Combining Images and Text articles)

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I'm tying to figure out how to use the GridView with different classes for groups.  In the GridApp template everything inherits from SampleDataCommon, do you always have to inherit from a common class in the GridView?  The documentation seems.. lacking on this mater.

**UPDATE:** 
Specifically the problem I'm trying to solve is to have a GridView with both image tiles and text news articles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind to any class type. I would *suggest* that they implement a common interface or class. If they cannot, then grouping them just does not make sense. You can display the items within the group by using a DataTemplateSelector. Here is a [very simple example](http://www.comyoucom.com/implementing-a-custom-datatemplateselector-in-winrt/) and a [more complex sample](http://www.wiredprairie.us/blog/index.php/archives/1705)