# Nested WrapGrid / GridView inside an item detail ScrollViewer?

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

**update 9/17/2012:** restated the question and added recreation steps

I'm trying to add a WrapGrid style image gallery to an ItemDetailPage.  So far the only solution I've found to achieve this is to create group styles and use a DataTemplate selector.  This seems like overkill to do this on a detail page as I would need to create a class for every column on my page.

I attempted to solve this as shown below but GridView scrolls independently of my ScrollViewer which is unacceptable.

To recreate start with the default Grid application in VS:

Add this property to SampleDataItem

```
// Add to SampleDataItem TODO: replace int with image url strings
private List<int> _subItems = null;
public List<int> SubItems
{
    get
    {
        if (_subItems == null)
        {
            _subItems = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
                this._subItems.Add(i);
        }
        return this._subItems;
    }
    set { this.SetProperty(ref this._subItems, value); }
}
```

in ItemDetailPage.xaml replace the RichTextColumns in the ScrollViewer:

```
 <!--Fixed column layout, replaces RichTextColumns from template-->    
  <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="800"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1400"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
            <Image x:Name="image" MaxHeight="480" Margin="0,20,0,10" Stretch="Uniform" Source="{Binding Image}"/>                                     
        </StackPanel>
        <GridView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled"  VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding SubItems}"  Grid.Column="1" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource GridViewDataTemplate1}" >
        </GridView>
    </Grid>
```

Finally add the following DataTemplate

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="GridViewDataTemplate1">
    <Grid Background="Yellow" Width="200" Height="200"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by setting the HorizontalScrollMode of the GridView to `Disabled`

```
<GridView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled" />
```

**However**, I would urge you to think about the best approach here. If the GridViews are not related to each, show them on separate pages. If they are related, then group one GridView. You can style the items of the groups differently using a [DataTemplateSelector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12152406/gridview-binding-to-groups-of-different-viewmodels-combining-images-and-text/12179853#12179853).

Comment: Setting it to Disabled didn't work for me.  I've restated my question and provided recreation steps.

Comment: kbeal2k: I discovered that you cannot place a GridView into a ScrollViewer, but you can place a many VariableSizedWrapGrids into the StackPanel